# seekbar deaccelaration graphics

Tags: android, multithreading, seekbar

I am trying to make a seekbar whose progress goes to 0 once you release. the program works just fine except for the graphics. i want the seekbar to display the progress reducing by 10 every second till it comes to zero.

i read somewhere that for graphics to update simultaneously we should use runOnUiThread but this doesn't work.

The progress bar shows the last position and zero but doesn't show the positions in between.
here's my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class seekbar_a extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{
    SeekBar sb;
    int progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.seekbar_a);
        sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar_acc);
        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }




    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int pro,
            boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pro=progress;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Progress = " + sb.getProgress() + "----\n----\n----\n----\n");
                sb.setProgress(sb.getProgress());
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        while (sb.getProgress() > 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Progress = " + sb.getProgress() + "====\n====\n====\n====\n");
            sb.setProgress(sb.getProgress()-10);
        }

    }

}
```

my thought process is this:
oncreate sets up the bar --> calls the onstarttrackingtouch method and then onprogresschange method till i let go of the thumb --> calls the onstoptrackingtouch method starts the loop which decrements progress that again calls onprogresschange method every second till 0.

then why are my graphics not changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runOnUiThread method in the onProgressChanged method is redundant, since that method is already called on the UI thread.

To do what you need, you'll need to edit your onStopTrachingTouch with this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {           
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {               
                while (sb.getProgress() > 0)
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                    {                       
                        @Override
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            sb.setProgress(sb.getProgress() - 10);

                        }
                    });                 
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
```

You'll need to write additional code to make sure that the previous thread is stopped if the user touches the progress bar again, but this should at least get you started.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks that worked absolutely fine.
I have just 2 more questions
1. why did you have to make a new thread.
2. does Thread.sleep stops the main 'Thread' or the 'thread' thread

Comment: 1. You want to have a thread that runs seperately (not on the UI thread), because otherwise, each sleep would put the UI thead to sleep. 2. Thread.sleep() stops the thread it was called from